# How does updating NSTableView from this mutable array work in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

In my application, I have an NSTableView which should contain a list of files. I have a button that is used to open an dialog and programmatically add files to this list. For some time, I could not get the table view to update when I was adding files, as I was using the following code:

```
[self.newPackage.files addObject:fileURL];
```

It makes sense to me now that this doesn't work. As I understand it, the above line of code would be changing the mutable array "behind the controller's back."

I was able to piece together a working solution, largely from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275593/cocoa-bindings-problem-bound-table-columns-dont-show-any-data-no-errors-in-con), with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *bindingsCompliantArray = [[self valueForKey:@"newPackage"] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"files"];
[bindingsCompliantArray addObject:fileURL];
```

However, I don't understand how this works. bindingsCompliantArray is not used anywhere else either. I've looked at the [documentation for mutableArrayValueForKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but it's not making it any clearer. Is there anyone that could help explain how this is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `‑mutableArrayValueForKey:` method returns a proxy array that you can treat as if it's the original array, with the added bonus that changes to the array are observed by any KVO observers watching the array.

`NSController` subclasses such as `NSArrayController` use Key-Value Observing to monitor changes to the objects they observe.

When you receive a proxy array via this method, `NSMutableArray` methods such as `‑addObject:` will be noticed by observers, whereas with a standard array this is not the case.

Comment: It took me over a month before I finally felt like I understood what was really going on here, but it seems your answer is spot on, albeit a bit vague for the Cocoa newbie (me). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293448/what-is-the-kvc-search-pattern-for-mutablearrayvalueforkey/2294715#2294715 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302365/observing-an-nsmutablearray-for-insertion-removal/304143#304143 were also helpful in helping me understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the addObject method to update the array and I think that the trouble remains there. Try to update it by setting a NEW array with the new value. It should work! =D

Good  luck!

Comment: The second snippet of code in my question does work, actually. I was more curious to know why or how it works.